# Parse output using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, parsing

I am using this library (PHP Simple HTML DOM parser) to parse a link, here's the code:

```
$htmlUrl = 'http://trailers.apple.com/trailers/independent/thelook/includes/playlists/web.inc';
$html = file_get_html($htmlUrl);
```

When I print with:

```
print_r($html . "\n");
```

**Outputs me this (html tree):**

```
<h2>
  <span class="dropdown-handle" id="trailers-handle">
    <span id='single-trailer-info'>Info</span>
    <span class='button'>
...
```

Then I want to find an element withe the class (dropdown-list):

```
$divList = $html->find('.dropdown-list'); // tried find('.dropdown-list', 0);
```

Then I print with:

```
print_r($divList);
```

**Outputs me this (array):**

```
simple_html_dom_node Object
(
    [nodetype] => 1
    [tag] => div
    [attr] => Array
        (
            [class] => dropdown-list
        )

    [children] => Array
...
```

**AND TAKES FOREVER PARSING!**

Am I doing something wrong?
Some links have this output (array) instead of output (html tree).

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: yes thats its behavior, its trying to get those elements recursively and yeah its going to be big and slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clear or close before the print_r  (sorry i forget which, just try one and then the other).

```
$html->clear();

$html->close();
```

If that doesn't work,  and you know the object you are "find"ing is a certain selector type, you should grab all of those first.  Then search through them,  that makes it go quicker if you are able to do that.   So if it's a `<select>` find all of those first, then run the find on those, or don't even use find and parse them yourself using `foreach` and `strpos`.

If that doesn't work, try fetching your pages first with `wget`, and then parsing them w/ html simple dom once you have saved them to your server.